# TI TPS6116 Output Voltage

Tags: boost, led-driver, backlight

I am designing an LED backlight driver as a sub-circuit for a DPI interface.  The backlight in question requires 12.8V.  I am trying to use the TPS61161 and have read through all of the documentation quite extensively.  What I don't understand is that the output voltage is "38V Max" and there is no reference to how the output voltage is set.  Vout is used in a few equations but as far as I can tell, not in a way that actually affects the Vout itself.

Am I missing something? Does the chip just sink any excess voltage as long as the load is in range?

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811061825_Texas-Instruments-TPS61161DRVR_C324075.pdf

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
This is all the information I have for the LED's:
[image: Backlight LED spec]

I have just wired up the following with a variable power supply that I have and got no illumination and a very hot power supply!  I thought this would work to dim the backlight from the pi?

[image: Test circuit]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Does it need constant voltage or constant current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Am I missing something?*

The TPS61161 can produce a maximum of 38 volts but its main aim is to provide a constant current for any LEDs connected. It does this by monitoring the current through \$R_{set}\$ below: -

[image]

In effect, the duty cycle of the TPS61161 is adjusted to force the required current through \$R_{set}\$ and whatever the peak voltage is at the top LED anode is whatever it needs to be to supply current through the LED string.

The FB pin needs to reach 200 mV and then the chip regulates so, in the circuit above, if 20 mA flows through the LEDs and \$R_{set}\$ is 10 ohms then 200 mV is produced at the FB pin and, the chip regulates that voltage by continually adjusting the duty cycle to maintain 20 mA through the LEDs.

> *The backlight in question requires 12.8V.*

The devil is in the detail so, without any other knowledge about the LED in question, it's impossible to say if the chip and its circuit is suitable.

Comment: Great, thanks that makes sense, this isn't the chip for me then

Comment: To be sure, link the data sheet for the LED @BasslineSoup

Comment: Thanks Andy, I added the info to the question along with an unsuccessful test circuit

Comment: @BasslineSoup you really need to try and dig out a proper data sheet for this part. You are out on a limb quality wise without it - also the circuit you have added with the transformer is never going to work. I'd consider stanrting a new question about using a flyback transformer drive if I were you but, that LED data sheet is vital.

Comment: Great thanks, I’ll get in touch with the manufacturer

Comment: All though just to clarify, that little transformer symbol actually represents a little boost converter I bought which is giving me 12.8v

Comment: Oh, OK, wrong symbol then LOL.

Answer (score 0):

It's a constant current driver. The voltage will rise to meet the requirements of the load,  but only to a point (38V).